# Cells reformat When adding calendar to sheet programmatically

Tags: vba, calendar, resize, format

I have a worksheet set up to show a report for a specific date or a specific month. When I add a single date (ex. 9/29/2016) everything is fine. But when I load my calendar and insert the entire month it puts a small calendar in the active cell but it will reformat all my column widths to match the width of the calendar days.(ex. Sunday will become A1, Monday B1, etc.) Is there a way to insert the calendar in to just one cell instead of it becoming 7 separate columns? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what the sheet looks like before adding the calendar.
[image]

This is after adding it.
[image]

I need to find a way to fit that calendar into one cell.

Comment: What exactly ***is*** the calendar that you're inserting? How are you inserting it? It looks like it's made up of a range of cells, not a single cell.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/AzccdCxT

Comment: Use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39781214/edit) and paste your code into your question. Only include the code relevant to your question.